# uniform convergence

Tags: integration, uniform-convergence

I need to find uniform convergence of integral $$I(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^aarctgx}{4+x^n}dx$$ where a from $$N=(0;n-1), n >2$$
I tried to do Weierstrass M-test. But I get $$I(a)<\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{d(x^n+4)}{4+x^n}dx$$ And this integral do not  converges.How to find uniform convergence ?

Comment: I don't understand why you mention uniform convergence, because there is no parameter $n \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle \forall x \in [0,+\infty): 0 \leq \arctan(x) < \frac{\pi}{2}$ we conclude 
$$\displaystyle I(a) < \int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{4+x^n}dx < \int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{x^n}dx$$ 
The integral on the right converges since $a < n-1$
$$ \int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{x^n}dx < \int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{x^n}dx =  \int_\limits{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx$$